# This function in python is not working properly

Tags: python-2.7

[image]    [image: This code is not running and giving me error can anyone please help]

*This code is giving me error, please help*

Comment: What error? And post code instead of screenshot

Comment: I am not able to post code here ! That is why i had posted the screenshot. It is giving me error invalid syntax  def TS(locked[0][0],ts):

Comment: And why can't you post code?

Comment: I tried it is not accepting plz see through this pic !

Comment: def TS(k[0],ts):
    for items in ts:
        if items[0]==k[0]:
            return items[1]


tsn=20
ts=[['t1', 10], ['t2', 20], ['t3', 30]]
locked=[['t1',['A','C']]]
for k in locked:
    if(TS(k[0],ts)<tsn):
        print "Wow"

Comment: and why on earth can't you edit the post and copy paste that in in the post instead of pasting in the comment box??

Comment: done the editing now ! Sorry

Comment: Please format your code, it's unreadable atm

Comment: Your edit actually made it worse. I have rolled it back. If you can't spend a minute to figure out how to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask don't expect any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a function in python you should write only titles of variables which it takes like this:

```
def my_func(a, b, next_var, another_var, etc):
    ...
```

But you wrote `def TS(k[0],ts):`, `k[0]` can't be a title of a variable, this is why your code has errors.

As a solution you can replace `k[0]` within your functions with `k0`.